# Postgres terminating connection because of crash of another server process

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have an issue with a daily job where there is a long running and memory heavy query executed in PostgreSQL 12.14 CloudSQL that usually takes 2h. About half way through the connection breaks with these errors:
first there is `WARNING:  57P02: terminating connection because of crash of another server process` followed by `FATAL:  57P03: the database system is in recovery mode` and then all other concurrent connections break as well because db is recovering. These are the only 2 statements i see in the logs.

Its happening for the last 2 days in a row and its always the same query. Important to note that after db recovers, query is retried and it always succeeds.
Can someone please help to understand what could be the reason? Could it be something with resources? CPU is reaching 100% at that moment of breakage(see pic: the last two loads around 6:30AM). However, this same query has been running ok previously with CPU reaching 100% as well and this was never an issue (the very first load on the pic). As i understand db restarts and frees the memory and that is why it always succeed on the second try. But im not a db expert.

I appreciate all the suggestions and comments!
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Looks like the OOM killer.  Make sure your work_mem is set to a reasonable value.  It is going to be very hard to investigate this without access to the underlying server, so maybe put the question to Google Clound support.

Comment: Your instance size is too small. Before contacting Google Cloud Support, increase the instance size for more CPU and memory.  Try to select a size that keeps the CPU peaks below 80%.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you for suggestion, i will try to play with work_mem first before increasing the resources.

Comment: Here is a link to help you with [work_mem](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/optimize-high-memory-usage). I would still choose a larger instance size, as changing work_mem will help you with OOM but probably not under sizing the CPU requirements.